# How to make the "reciprocal power" appear using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

Using the following MWE, siunitx won't display the expected `^{-1}` at the end of the expression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale = FR]{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,per-symbol=\text{.}}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\si{\kilogram\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

I think I'm following the documentation correctly but I must be missing something.
Any input very welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you're looking to get is `kg m s^{-1}` out of `\si{\kilogram\metre\per\second}`, you should *not* use `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,per-symbol=\text{.}}`. The default per-mode setting is, actually, `reciprocal`. If the default setting isn't in force for some reason, just issue the directive

```
\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}
```

before running, say, `\si{\metre\per\second}` (or, if you prefer, `\si{\meter\per\second}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale = FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\si{\metre\per\second}    % use default setting, which is 'reciprocal'
\quad
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol} % default per-mode symbol is "/"
\si{\metre\per\second}
\quad
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,per-symbol=\text{.}} % use another character as per-mode symbol
\si{\metre\per\second}
\quad
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}   % switch to fraction mode
\si{\metre\per\second}
\quad
\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal} % back to the default
\si{\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP: If interest lies in rendering the output of `\si{\metre\per\second}` as `m.s{-1}`, the `per-mode` option is not relevant. Instead, you probably want

```
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\text{.}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale = FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\si{\meter\per\second} % default inter-unit separator is thin-space
\quad
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\text{.}}
\si{\meter\per\second}
\quad
\sisetup{inter-unit-product={\,}} % back to default
\si{\meter\per\second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. The thing is, we would like to obtain m.s^{-1}... a mix of your third and fifth example.

Comment: @SébastienMengin -  What you need, then, is `\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\text{.}}`, *not* `\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,per-symbol=\text{.}}`.

Comment: Many thanks ! this is exactly what I was looking for.